# Vue.js - Pass prop into $.each() (in mounted)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, each

I need to iterate over an object literal when my component is mounted. But I struggle to use the prop data inside my `.each()` function. Inside the `each()` function the prop data is 'undefined' when I check with `console.log`. My code looks like this:

```
    [..]
      props: {
       active_categories: String,  // example: "0,1,2,4", might also be NULL
       category_list: Array  // example: [ 0:{ID:0, Status:0}, 1:{ID:1, Status:0} [..] ]
      },
    
      mounted: function(){

        // iterate through the prop array 'category_list'
        // if an ID of this array is included in the string 'active_categories', 
        // set 'Status=1'
          
        $.each(this.category_list, function(key, value, active_categories) {
    
            if(active_categories){
    
              if(active_categories.includes(value.ID)){
                   value.Status = 1;
                 }
                 
            }
      
         });
```

How can I bring the prop value(s) inside my `.each()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `this` to a global variable called `self` then use it inside the `$.each` callback because `this` inside that callback has a different context :

```
  mounted: function(){

        let self=this
          
        $.each(this.category_list, function(key, value) {
    
            if(self.active_categories){
    
              if(self.active_categories.includes(value.ID)){
                   value.Status = 1;
                 }
                 
            }
      
         });
```